# how to change col-span when a data is added to html table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the timetable for a student to register,a student can select the class to add to the timetable.

Now, I have a problem: I don't know how to add col-span automatically when the new class is added to the timetable.

Any well-developed project or jQuery or technique I can refer to? Can you share it with me? Thank you.

First the timetable is blank:
[image]

After add a new class:
[image]

Here's my code (no javascript and JQuery, the result I typed it by myself):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <style>
      td {
        padding: 5px;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <table width="80%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
      <tr valign="middle">
        <th rowspan="2" width="50" scope="col">Day/Time</th>
        <th colspan="2" class="col">
          <div align="center">07:00</div>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" class="col">
          <div align="center">08:00</div>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" class="col">
          <div align="center">09:00</div>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" class="col">
          <div align="center">10:00</div>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" class="col">
          <div align="center">11:00</div>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" class="col">
          <div align="center">12:00</div>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" class="col">
          <div align="center">01:00</div>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" class="col">
          <div align="center">02:00</div>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" class="col">
          <div align="center">03:00</div>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" class="col">
          <div align="center">04:00</div>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" class="col">
          <div align="center">05:00</div>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2" scope="col">
          <div align="center">08:00</div>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" scope="col">
          <div align="center">09:00</div>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" scope="col">
          <div align="center">10:00</div>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" scope="col">
          <div align="center">11:00</div>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" scope="col">
          <div align="center">12:00</div>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" scope="col">
          <div align="center">01:00</div>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" scope="col">
          <div align="center">02:00</div>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" scope="col">
          <div align="center">03:00</div>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" scope="col">
          <div align="center">04:00</div>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" scope="col">
          <div align="center">05:00</div>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" scope="col">
          <div align="center">06:00</div>
      </tr>
      <tr align="center">
        <th>Mon</th>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="center">
        <th>Tue</th>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        </td>
        <td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </td>
        <td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="center">
        <th>Wed</th>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        </td>
        <td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="center">
        <th>Thu</th>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        </td>
        <td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="center">
        <th>Fri</th>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        </td>
        <td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <div style="padding-left: 150px">
      <h4>Class Available:</h3>
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
    <th>Class</th>
    <th>Day</th>
    <th>Time</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Class A</td>
    <td>Tue</td>
    <td>09.00am - 12.00am</td>
    </tr>
    <td>Class B</td>
    <td>Mon</td>
    <td>10.00am - 01.00pm</td>
    </tr>
    <td>Class C</td>
    <td>Thu</td>
    <td>04.00pm - 05.00pm</td>
    </tr>
    <td>Class D</td>
    <td>Fri</td>
    <td>01.00pm - 02.00pm</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <label>Class: </label><input type="text"/> <input type="button" value="Add"/>
</div>
<table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After I go and study some code, here would be my better solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
td{
    padding:5px;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var inputClass = "";
    var day = "";
    var time = "";
    var count = 1;
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("input[type='button']").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        inputClass = $("input[type='text']").val()
        getDayAndtime();
      })
    })

    function getDayAndtime() {
      $("#classAvailable td").each(function() {

        if ($(this).text() === inputClass) {
          day = $(this).siblings(":nth-of-type(2)").text();
          time = $(this).siblings(":nth-of-type(3)").text();
        bookClas();

        }
      })
    }
    var timeGap = '';

    var colspanMon = 0;
    var colspanTue = 0;
    var colspanWed = 0;
    var colspanThu = 0;
    var colspanFri = 0;

    function bookClas() {

                var colspan = checkDurationOfClass() * 2
                var row = document.getElementById(day);

                var colspanNum = 0;
                if(day === "Mon")
                colspanNum += colspanMon
                if(day === "Tue")
                colspanNum += colspanTue
                if(day === "Wed")
                colspanNum += colspanWed
                if(day === "Thu")
                colspanNum += colspanThu
                if(day === "Fri")
                colspanNum += colspanFri

                for(var j = colspan; j < colspan + colspan ; j++){
                    row.deleteCell(timeGap + 1 - colspanNum);
                    }

                var cell = row.insertCell(timeGap + 1 - colspanNum);
                cell.innerHTML = inputClass;
                cell.setAttribute("colspan", colspan);
                cell.style.backgroundColor = "green";


            if(day === "Mon")
            colspanMon = colspan - 1;
            if(day === "Tue")
            colspanTue = colspan - 1;
            if(day === "Wed")
            colspanWed = colspan - 1;
            if(day === "Thu")
            colspanThu = colspan - 1;
            if(day === "Fri")
            colspanFri = colspan - 1;

    }

  function checkDurationOfClass(){
    time = time.split(' - ')

        var duration = ConvertTimeformat("24", time[1]) - ConvertTimeformat("24", time[0]);
         timeGap =  ConvertTimeformat("24", time[0]) - ConvertTimeformat("24", "07.00am");
         timeGap = (timeGap/60) * 2;
    console.log(timeGap);

    return duration /= 60
  }

  function ConvertTimeformat(format, time) {
    var hours = Number(time.match(/^(\d+)/)[1]);
    var minutes = Number(time.match(/\.(\d+)/)[1]);
    var AMPM = time.match(/\D(\D.*)$/)[0];

    if (AMPM == "pm" && hours < 12) hours = hours + 12;
    if (AMPM == "am" && hours == 12) hours = hours - 12;

    minutes += hours * 60

    return minutes
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<table id="schema" width="80%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
  <tr valign="middle">
    <th rowspan="2" width="50" scope="col">Day/Time</th>
    <th colspan="2" class="col">
      <div align="center">07:00</div>
    </th>
    <th colspan="2" class="col">
      <div align="center">08:00</div>
    </th>
    <th colspan="2" class="col">
      <div align="center">09:00</div>
    </th>
    <th colspan="2" class="col">
      <div align="center">10:00</div>
    </th>
    <th colspan="2" class="col">
      <div align="center">11:00</div>
    </th>
    <th colspan="2" class="col">
      <div align="center">12:00</div>
    </th>
    <th colspan="2" class="col">
      <div align="center">01:00</div>
    </th>
    <th colspan="2" class="col">
      <div align="center">02:00</div>
    </th>
    <th colspan="2" class="col">
      <div align="center">03:00</div>
    </th>
    <th colspan="2" class="col">
      <div align="center">04:00</div>
    </th>
    <th colspan="2" class="col">
      <div align="center">05:00</div>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" scope="col">
      <div align="center">08:00</div>
    </th>
    <th colspan="2" scope="col">
      <div align="center">09:00</div>
    </th>
    <th colspan="2" scope="col">
      <div align="center">10:00</div>
    </th>
    <th colspan="2" scope="col">
      <div align="center">11:00</div>
    </th>
    <th colspan="2" scope="col">
      <div align="center">12:00</div>
    </th>
    <th colspan="2" scope="col">
      <div align="center">01:00</div>
    </th>
    <th colspan="2" scope="col">
      <div align="center">02:00</div>
    </th>
    <th colspan="2" scope="col">
      <div align="center">03:00</div>
    </th>
    <th colspan="2" scope="col">
      <div align="center">04:00</div>
    </th>
    <th colspan="2" scope="col">
      <div align="center">05:00</div>
    </th>
    <th colspan="2" scope="col">
      <div align="center">06:00</div>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center" id="Mon">
    <th>Mon</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>

    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>

    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>

  </tr>
  <tr align="center" id="Tue">
    <th>Tue</th>
  <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>

    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center" id="Wed">
    <th>Wed</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>

    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center" id="Thu">
    <th>Thu</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>

    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center" id="Fri">
    <th>Fri</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
  </tr>
</table>


<div style="padding-left: 150px">
  <h4>Class Available:</h4>
  <table id="classAvailable" border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Class</th>
      <th>Day</th>
      <th>Time</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Class A</td>
      <td>Tue</td>
      <td>09.30am - 12.00pm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Class B</td>
      <td>Mon</td>
      <td>10.00am - 01.00pm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Class C</td>
      <td>Mon</td>
      <td>04.00pm - 05.00pm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Class D</td>
      <td>Fri</td>
      <td>01.00pm - 02.00pm</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br/>
  <label>Class:</label>
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="button" value="Add" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [this](http://www.redips.net/javascript/drag-and-drop-table-content/) mixed with [that](http://www.redips.net/javascript/table-td-merge-split/). Both are JavaScript table plugins written by [Darko Bunic](http://www.redips.net/about/).

Answer (score 0):

You must be check where you can add the data in your table and with `.attr()` you can `colspan` the table.

Please try below:

```js
$("#add").click(function(){
  $(".Mon").find("td:eq(6)").html($("#classe").val()).attr("colspan","2")
  $(".Mon").find("td:last").remove()
})
```

```css
td{
  padding:5px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="80%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
      <tr valign="middle">
        <th rowspan="2" width="50" scope="col">Day/Time</th>
        <th colspan="2" class="col">
          <div align="center">07:00</div>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" class="col">
          <div align="center">08:00</div>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" class="col">
          <div align="center">09:00</div>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" class="col">
          <div align="center">10:00</div>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" class="col">
          <div align="center">11:00</div>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" class="col">
          <div align="center">12:00</div>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" class="col">
          <div align="center">01:00</div>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" class="col">
          <div align="center">02:00</div>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" class="col">
          <div align="center">03:00</div>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" class="col">
          <div align="center">04:00</div>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" class="col">
          <div align="center">05:00</div>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2" scope="col">
          <div align="center">08:00</div>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" scope="col">
          <div align="center">09:00</div>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" scope="col">
          <div align="center">10:00</div>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" scope="col">
          <div align="center">11:00</div>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" scope="col">
          <div align="center">12:00</div>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" scope="col">
          <div align="center">01:00</div>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" scope="col">
          <div align="center">02:00</div>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" scope="col">
          <div align="center">03:00</div>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" scope="col">
          <div align="center">04:00</div>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" scope="col">
          <div align="center">05:00</div>
        </th>
        <th colspan="2" scope="col">
          <div align="center">06:00</div>
      </tr>
      <tr class="Mon" align="center">
        <th>Mon</th>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="center">
        <th>Tue</th>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        </td>
        <td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </td>
        <td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="center">
        <th>Wed</th>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        </td>
        <td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="center">
        <th>Thu</th>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        </td>
        <td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="center">
        <th>Fri</th>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        </td>
        <td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <div style="padding-left: 150px">
      <h4>Class Available:</h3>
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
    <th>Class</th>
    <th>Day</th>
    <th>Time</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Class A</td>
    <td>Tue</td>
    <td>09.00am - 12.00am</td>
    </tr>
    <td>Class B</td>
    <td>Mon</td>
    <td>10.00am - 01.00pm</td>
    </tr>
    <td>Class C</td>
    <td>Thu</td>
    <td>04.00pm - 05.00pm</td>
    </tr>
    <td>Class D</td>
    <td>Fri</td>
    <td>01.00pm - 02.00pm</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <label>Class: </label><input id="classe" type="text"/> <input id="add" type="button" value="Add"/>
</div>
<table>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, after I study your code, I notice your code is match only exactly my case, that is great. However, for the other cases, I mean if there are a lot of selection, your code is no longer suitable because your code is not scale-able.

Answer (score 0):

So, please see my updated working code here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bfj43ks5/8/) I have updated it so if a class is more the 1h it will show on the Schema.

```
    var inputClass = "";
    var day = "";
    var time = "";

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("input[type='button']").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        inputClass = $("input[type='text']").val()
        getDayAndtime();
      })
    })

    function getDayAndtime() {
      $("#classAvailable td").each(function() {

        if ($(this).text() === inputClass) {
          day = $(this).siblings(":nth-of-type(2)").text();
          time = $(this).siblings(":nth-of-type(3)").text();
        bookClas();
        }
      })
    }

    function bookClas() {
      $("#schema div").each(function(i) {
          if ($(this).is(":contains('" + time.match(/\d+/) + "')")) {
            i *= 2;

                    var colspan = checkDurationOfClass() * 2

            $("#schema th:contains('" + day + "')")
            .siblings(":nth-of-type(" + (i + 1) + ")")
            .attr('colspan', colspan)
            .html(inputClass)
            .css('background', 'green')

            for(var j = 0; j < colspan - 1; j++){
            $("#schema th:contains('" + day + "')").siblings(":nth-of-type(" + (i + j) + ")").last().remove()
          }
          }
        })
    }

  function checkDurationOfClass(){
    time = time.split(' - ')

        var duration = ConvertTimeformat("24", time[1]) - ConvertTimeformat("24", time[0]);
    console.log(duration)

    return duration /= 60
  }

  function ConvertTimeformat(format, time) {
    var hours = Number(time.match(/^(\d+)/)[1]);
    var minutes = Number(time.match(/\.(\d+)/)[1]);
    var AMPM = time.match(/\D(\D.*)$/)[0];

    if (AMPM == "pm" && hours < 12) hours = hours + 12;
    if (AMPM == "am" && hours == 12) hours = hours - 12;

    minutes += hours * 60

    return minutes
  }
```

Comment: And why are you down voting my answer?

Comment: Thanks a lot, your code work fine for colspan, but after I insert a new class, there will have an extra cell pop out at the right hand-side...

Comment: How do you mean? Pleas edit my fiddle and post the link here.

Comment: Do you try your code? If not you try it, you will notice there is a new column will be added from right hand-side if you insert new class...

Comment: Sorry, did not see that first. Now my code is updated and I added             .next('td').remove(); to the element selector to deal with the added column.

Comment: Wow, brilliant, btw, if I would like to remove it, I mean when the user want to deselect the class, how would I do it? Sorry for suddenly add the requirement...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126316/discussion-between-zorken17-and-chong-zheng-lun).

Comment: Go into the chat!